# 'Not an answer' flag on a comment-like answer was declined - Shouldn't I flag these?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged as not-an-answer this one:

*[How to send an enquiry command with DirectIO() in POS for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649399/how-to-send-an-enquiry-command-with-directio-in-pos-for-net/47524229#47524229)*

But my flag was declined for the reason:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

[image: Flag declined]

I genuinely think it fits the "Not an answer" flag reason. It sounds more like a request for clarification than a true answer to the question.

Is it a mistake from the flag reviewer(s?)? Am I mistaken, should I have done nothing, or done anything else in this case?

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131996/318307

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301397/259412) I wrote a suggestion, what is in my opinion, what is the optimal behavior if your flag is declined. You may find it useful.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you think that suggesting an answer in the form of a question isn't answering the question?  Why would **suggesting an answer** merit deletion as Not An Answer just because that answer contains a grammatical question?  Do you just not like rhetorical questions?

Comment: No, it's not about the grammar, it's about the fact  the answerer was not even sure about his suggestion solving the issue, he only tried to give a investigation direction. He was seemingly waiting for feedback from OP. In these situations it seems to me that the usual way to go is to discuss this in comments, and eventually, if the clues end up to some actual solution, turn it into an answer only at this point. I am probably mistaken, just asking here on meta to clarify if people like me should flag this kind of answer or not.

Comment: @Pac0 When someone *provides an answer*, then the answer isn't Not An Answer.  Even if they're not sure about their answer.  Someone not being confident in their answer doesn't make it Not An Answer.

Comment: @Pac0, from the help center, on "how do I write a good answer". "Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on"